# Editable-Text with angular JS acts like a normal link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

Can you help what i am doing wrong here?

I implemented an editable label with angular js in one of my forms using xeditable and angular  but the strange is that the editable label acts like a normal link, i followed this doc

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

Here is my relevent html code

```html
        <a href="#"  editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
```

I am inserting the angular js controller and everything, i get no error it is just that it acts like a normal link.

EDIT my app.js looks like

```js
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('myApp', [
                               'ngResource',
                               'ngRoute',
                               'ngFileUpload',
                               'angularBootstrapNavTree',
                               'ngAnimate',
                               'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
                               "checklist-model",
                               'xeditable'


                             ]);



 //comment
App.config(['$routeProvider','paginationTemplateProvider', function($routeProvider,paginationTemplateProvider) {
 ......

}]);

App.run(['$rootScope','$location','$routeParams','$http','Attribut','Categorie','SsCategorieofcategorie','Produit','ConfigCategorie','editableOptions', function($rootScope, $location, $routeParams, $http, Attribut, Categorie,SsCategorieofcategorie,Produit,ConfigCategorie,editableOptions) {
   editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
........

    }]);
```

And my controller :

```js
'var strict';

App.controller('GenerationContenuController',['$scope', '$http','$interval','GenerationContenu','InputText','$timeout',  function($scope, $http,$interval,GenerationContenu,InputText ,$timeout){

    var self=this;
    
        $scope.user = {
          name: 'awesome user'
        };



...



}]);
```

and finally the html

```html
<form id="msform"  ng-controller="GenerationContenuController as ctrl"  editable-form>
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Choix du contenu</li>
    <li>Validation du vocabulaire</li>
    <li>Validation du contenu </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Choix du contenu</h2>
        <a href="#"  editable-text="user.name">{{ user.name || "empty" }}</a>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="inputText" ng-model="typeInputText" ng-change="ctrl.update()" required>
                <option value="MOT CLE">Mots cles</option>
                <option value="PHRASE">Phrases bateau</option>
                <option value="AVIS">Faux avis</option>
                <option value="CONSEIL">Conseils pour parents</option>
           </select>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedInputText" required>
                <option ng-repeat="inputText in inputTexts" value="{{inputText.text}}">{{inputText.text}}</option>
           </select>
           </div>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" ng-click="ctrl.genererVocabulaire()" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>

    <fieldSet>
    ....
  </fieldSet>
     <fieldSet>
    ....
   </fieldSet>
</form>

  </div>
```

I tried to put the max and keep specific in the same time

Comment: Please provide more code. With the current code, we can't find the problem.

Comment: Jordumus i edited the post please take a look and thank you in advance

Comment: Please post all of our angular code and html code.

Comment: Sorry  sebenalern i didn't get what you mean if you mean the   angular-xeditable/xeditable.js (the css too) downloaded from https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/ i didn't modify it i kept it as it is

Comment: You included this in your html? `<link href="angular-xeditable/css/xeditable.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="angular-xeditable/js/xeditable.js"></script>`?

Comment: yes i included both in my index.html (the main template for all the project)

Comment: when i inspect the editable-text i find this 
<a href="#" editable-text="user.name" class="ng-scope ng-binding editable">awesome user</a>

i suppose that the editable name in the class of the link is a proof that those files are correctly imported, what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here : `<form id="msform"  ng-controller="GenerationContenuController as ctrl"  editable-form>`.In other words you have used `controller as` syntax.Either remove it or use latest Angular version with it.Hope this will help to you.

Here is the Fiddle which it is working without `controller as` syntax.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14883/)

Here is the Fiddle with latest Angular version and with `controller as` syntax:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14885/)

**UPDATE :**

If you need to use it within the form then you have to do it differently.

```
<span editable-text="user.name" e-name="name" onbeforesave="checkName($data)" e-
required>{{ user.name || 'empty' }}</span>
```

Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14896/)

Comment: you are right Sampath, i figured out that the problem is the form itself i implemented it in when i tried it outside the form it worked but once in the form it doesn't still don't know how i can solve this

PS: i user angular 1.5.0

Comment: Why can't you set all your concerns on the Fiddle ? Then we can help to you no? One thing ,this is very simple issue to sort out.

Comment: i have to say that i am obligated to use the form for other constraints, i tried to surround the div with the form tag in the fiddle you gave me and it works  i don't know it is weird

Comment: Sure i will i was delaying that just because there is a lot of resources, just some laziness i will give it to you in a few minutes

Comment: What resources ? If you `fork` one of my above fiddle then you have all the resources no ?

Comment: It is just because in my controller i work with other Angular services etc ....

Sorry for the mess this is my first try with fiddle (you made me try a new thing big thank,s for that)  it is supposed to be a multisteps form :D  i will put how it is in reality in a scrrenshot in the post.

http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14883/

Comment: i have just seen your last comment i will see

Comment: After modifying you have to `Update` the fiddle and need to put that new fiddle url here.Above one is not yours,it is my one.

Comment: Yes,If you're using `X-editable forms` then you have to use it as I mentioned above.You cannot use it the way you have used right now.That is the issue here.Hope you'll get the point.

Comment: the problem is that the main form is linked to another important action, actually i need the editable text in the third field set to make the labels  of the "phrases " check boxes editable

Comment: If you're using `x-editable forms` then it must be the way I have mentioned above.You cannot use any other way (mix of things).That is the way this `api` has been developed.Please see the `api doc`.https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-form

Comment: Okey Simpath thank you so much for your patience, you couldn't be more helpful